# How to prevent Mono from stretching the windows in a WinForms application vertically (on linux)?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, winforms, mono

The title is quite descriptive I think.
My Winforms applications are running on Mono but there is an annoying problem: all my windows in the application are stretched vertically about 1.5 times. So my square shaped buttons and windows become rectangles. Only the sizes are scretched font sizes are not. So there are big gaps in the layout.

Does anyone have ideas how to fix this? Is it bug in Mono?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally due to autoscaling:

http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Winforms#My_forms_are_sized_improperly

Comment: Good catch, but wouldn't that mean that the fonts would've been changed as well (he says they are not)?

Comment: If he is running Mono on Linux, then the fonts are going to be different because Windows and Linux have different fonts.  Also, it isn't the font point that dictates this, its the actual height/width ratio of the font used.

Comment: ahh "autoscaling" and "improperly sized forms". I searched on the google with wrong keywords. thx all.